# Can iphone web apps, be put on appstore for sale, just like native apps?

Tags: iphone, app-store, web-applications

Can iphone web apps be sold on appstore, without requiring user to do manual bookmark, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create webapps and put them in the [IStore under webapps](https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?appIdKey=D534F5C413E680ACBC861EE8025883117C9705F90893AF782751628F0291F620&path=/iphone/index.php)

As per the page ...
To submit an iPhone web application, review the following guidelines, then log into the submission system using the Apple ID and password associated with your ADC membership.

You must be an Apple Developer Connection (ADC) Online, Select, or Premier member to participate in this program. If you are not a member, you can join for free and then return to this site to complete the submission process.

To be considered, you submission must meet the following guidelines:

- You must agree to the iPhone Web
  Application Submission Agreement for
  all materials submitted for
  consideration.
- Your submission must conform to the
  iPhone web development guidelines in
  effect at the time of your
  submission.
- Your submission should have a
  complete feature set (stable releases
  and demos are preferred to beta
  software).
- Your submission (and the content
  displayed in or through your
  submission) must not violate or
  infringe the intellectual property
  rights (including trademark rights)
  of others. You must either own all
  rights to your submission and the
  content displayed in or through the
  submission or have written
  authorization from the owner(s)
  thereof.
- You must provide at least one working
  link to access your submission.   By
  submitting applications for
  consideration to the iPhone Web
  Application Submission page, you
  understand your submission is subject
  to review by Apple. Apple reserves
  the right to omit, edit, or reject
  submissions.

Comment: The Web app does not actually appear in the App Store though. The web apps are only searchable in Safari: www.apple.com./webapps. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 1):

Just build a hybrid app. Hybrid wraps your html/css/javascript code in a native container which will give your app the ability to be distributed on an app store.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, no. But you could potentially create a native iPhone app that just contains a UIWebView pointing to your mobile optimized site. I highly doubt Apple would approve this but I'm not positive.